# How to connect from spring boot kafka project to aws MSK

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, aws-msk

I am trying to connect to a aws msk cluster from spring boot kafka app.

i have aws msk arn ,boot strap server config available.

How to integrate in the application?
Any examples

Can i run it from local,i mean connect to AWS MSK from local app  instance

[msk cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mKhi.png)

Comment: What issues are you having? What does your code look like?

Comment: I cannot post the code here

Comment: Hi did you find any solution? i am also facing same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Connection to AWS MSK is like connecting to any Kafka cluster.

It depends on how you had setup your MSK ? (VPC - Subnet)
Check whether you can access from your local or need to be on VPN.

Also see how your brokers endpoints are configured and exposed - 
Ex:

- Plaintext (broker:9092)
- TLS (broker:9094)

If its plaintext, its as simple as setting bootstrap.servers.

Otherwise, you need to add below mentioned properties to access your MSK cluster.

```
security.protocol: SSL
ssl.truststore.location: jks
ssl.truststore.password: pwd
```

Please let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: We do not have client ssl authentication ON. So do we need the password and location? updated image

Comment: Nope, then you dont need those two properties and security.protocol would be PLAINTEXT.

Comment: finally we had to put ssl. asper https://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/kafka/ssl.html#configuring-kafka-clientsonly along with     //props.put("ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "");However did not need trust store !!as probably both app deployed on ec2 and msk are in same vpn? or is this something automacially by aws

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect from `kafka-console-*` commands (or simpler, `kafkacat`) then you should be able to connect from any other application.

I suggest you debug using those tools before running anything else.